# How to restrict user from viewing/accessing the cached files from file explorer in an Android Device?

Tags: android, security, caching

My requirement is to cache the files securely in android internal/external storage, where apps other than my app should not view/access the documents I store.

Current implementation:

Currently, the app uses `context.getExternalCacheDir()` as a base directory and followed by respective folder structure to cache files. The problem here is, any user can view the files stored by just navigating through the path using some File Explorer apps.

We can use `context.getCacheDir()` or file directory,
There are limitations in using it, as it has less space and the platform might automatically delete files when it wants space for other operations.

Required Implementation:
Encryption/decryption would be one way yet, please suggest other possible ways to cache the files securely, so that users cannot view/access using other external applications.

Comment: If you don't want the files to be deleted by system - don't use cache directories. If you want the files to be not accessible for other apps - use internal storage. In most cases internal and external storages share the same disk space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as it has less space

That is not true for most Android devices created in the last 8 years.

> the platform might automatically delete files when it wants space for other operations

That also holds true for `getExternalCacheDir()`.

> please suggest other possible ways to cache the files securely, so that user cannot view/access using other external application

Use `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: it's a little late but for future reader check out scoped storage : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage